# Question about operators and the closure of their range

Tags: functional-analysis

This is from Teschl's Linear and Non-linear functional analysis, problem 1.50. on page 38.

Let $X := C[0, 1]$. Investigate the operator $A : X \to X$,
$f(x) \to x f(x)$. Show that this is a bounded linear operator and compute its
norm. What is the closure of $\text{Ran}(A)$?

I think that the linearity is trivial (just look at $A(f+g)$...). For the boundedness I have that

$$||Af|| = ||xf(x)|| = |x|\cdot||f(x)|| \leq ||f(x)||$$

since $x$ is bounded by 1. So we have $||A|| \leq 1$. To show that this is our norm, we use the function $f(x) = \frac{x}{|x| + \epsilon}$ with $\epsilon > 0$ which gives us

$$||Af|| = \biggl|\biggl|\frac{x^2}{|x| + \epsilon}\biggr|\biggr| \geq \biggl|\biggl|\frac{x^2 - \epsilon^2}{|x| + \epsilon}\biggr|\biggr| = \frac{(|x| - \epsilon)\cdot(|x| + \epsilon)}{|x| + \epsilon} = |x| - \epsilon$$

Since this holds for all $x \in [0,1]$, it especially holds for $x = 1$ and we have $||Af|| \geq 1 - \epsilon$. Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, we have $||A|| = 1$.

I just wanted to ask, if my approach is correct and if somebody could help me with the last question regarding the closure of $\text{Ran}(A)$. I know that $\text{Ran}(A) = \{Ax \ | \ x \in D(A)\}$ but I really struggle to find the closure of $\text{Ran}(A)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are given the usual sup norm on $X$.

$||Af|| = ||xf(x)|| = |x|\cdot||f(x)|| \leq ||f(x)||$ does not even make sense.

You should write

$|Af(x)| = |xf(x)| = |x||f(x)| \leq ||f||$, so $\|Af\|\leq \|f\|$. Thus, $\|A\|\leq 1$.

To show that $\|A\|=1$ define $f_n(x)=0$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1-\frac  1 n$ and $f_n(x)=n(x+\frac 1 n-1)$ for $1-\frac 1 n <x\leq 1$. Note that $\|f_n\|=1$ and $Af_n(1)=1f_n(1)=1$ Hence, $\|Af_n\|\geq 1$ which gives $\|A\| \geq 1$.

Note that every function $g$ in the range of $A$ has the property that $\frac {g{(x)}} x$ is continuous.  In fact, the converse is also true.

I claim that the closure of the range consists of all continuous function $g$ such that $g(0)=0$. To see this take any such function $g$ and define $f_n(x)=0$ for $0 \leq x \leq \frac1 n$, $f_n(x)=g(x)$ for $x >\frac   2n$ and $f_n(x)=n(x-\frac 1 n) g(\frac  2 n)$ for $\frac1 n < x \leq \frac 2 n$. I will let you verify that $f_n \to g$ uniformly.

Alternative proof for the last part: Using Wierstrass Theorem choose  a polynomial $p$ such that $|g(x)-p(x)| <\epsilon /2$ for all $x$. If $q(x)=p(x)-p(0)$ then $q $ belongs the range of $A$ and $|g(x)-q(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x$.